# how do i encrypt and decrypt use AES/GCM/ between PHP and JAVA

Tags: java, php, aes-gcm

I use PHP to encrypt use AES/GCM to communicate with JAVA，but it does not work。 This is the code。I don't know where is the wrong?

```php
<?php

$key = "123456789012345678901234567890";
$plaintext = "aaaaaaa";
$encryptStr = aesGcmEncrypt($plaintext, $key);
echo "加密后：" . $encryptStr;


function aesGcmEncrypt($plaintext, $key)
{

    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher = "aes-128-gcm");
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING, $iv, $tag);
    $ciphertext = base64_encode($iv . $ciphertext_raw . $tag);
    return $ciphertext;
}

function decrypt($str, $key)
{
    $encrypt = base64_decode($str);
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher = "aes-128-gcm");
    $tag_length = 16;
    $iv = substr($encrypt, 0, $ivlen);
    $tag = substr($encrypt, -$tag_length);
    $ciphertext = substr($encrypt, $ivlen, -$tag_length);

    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING, $iv, $tag);
    return $ciphertext_raw;
}
```

this is the java code。

```
private static String aesGcmEncrypt(String content, byte[] key) {
        try {
            System.out.println(content);
            System.out.println(content.getBytes(UTF_8).length);
            // 根据指定算法ALGORITHM自成密码器
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/PKCS5Padding");
            SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skey);
            //获取向量
            byte[] ivb = cipher.getIV();
            byte[] encodedByteArray = cipher.doFinal(content.getBytes(UTF_8));

            byte[] message = new byte[ivb.length + encodedByteArray.length];

            System.arraycopy(ivb, 0, message, 0, ivb.length);
            System.arraycopy(encodedByteArray, 0, message, ivb.length, encodedByteArray.length);
            String ss = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(message);
            return ss;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException
                | BadPaddingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

JAVA code can't modify,because it is not mine,I must adapt to the java code.

Comment: In the Java code you specifically add PKCS#5 (better to say PKCS#7) padding, but you `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING` in the PHP code

Comment: On Java-side the algorithm-key is defined by the length of the key (e.g. using a 128 bit = 16 byte long key will give you AES 128 GCM mode, a 256 bit = 32 byte long key will end in AES 256 GCM). On PHP-side you need to specify "hard coded" the algorithm (e.g. "aes-128-gcm" or "aes-192-gcm" or "aes-256-gcm"). Second point: just use "OPENSSL_RAW_DATA" as option and leave out "OPENSSL_NO_PADDING" as already commented by @Bram.

Answer (score 2):

Both codes probably behave differently than you expect.

In the Java code no padding is used at all, although `PKCS5Padding` (in Java a synonym for PKCS7Padding) is specified. The SunJCE Provider disables the specified `PKCS5Padding` for GCM and applies `NoPadding`. This is useful because [GCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) is a stream cipher mode that does not require padding.
It should be mentioned that the behavior is version dependent. Only earlier JDK versions (e.g. 8, 11, 12) accept `PKCS5Padding` for GCM and run it as `NoPadding`. Later JDK versions (e.g. 14, 15), in contrast, raise an exception. Also, other providers may behave differently.

In the PHP code the ciphertext is returned by `openssl_encrypt` as raw data and therefore is only Base64 encoded once (namely after concatenation with IV and tag), as it should be. Thus the code behaves as if the flag `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` is set. This is because [`OPENSSL_NO_PADDING`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) (with the value 3) is used, which is actually only defined for asymmetric encryption but not for symmetric encryption, and therefore should not be applied here at all. Flags for symmetric encryption are `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` (with the value 1) and `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` (with the value 2), so that `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING` is equivalent to `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`, thus implicitly setting `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`.
Note that `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` does not enable Zero padding, but disables the default PKCS7 padding. Similar to the SunJCE Provider, also openssl implicitly disables the default PKCS7 padding for GCM, i.e. no matter if `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` is set or not, no padding is used for GCM.

In summary it can be said that padding and flags are ruled out as the reasons for the error: In both codes there is no padding applied, in the PHP code `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` is set.

Unfortunately you did not describe the error, so just guesses are possible. Probably the issue is caused by incompatible keys, since both codes work on my machine and are compatible.
As already mentioned in the comments, for AES-128/192/256 a 16/24/32 bytes key must be used. In the Java code the length of the key determines the AES variant, i.e. a length of e.g. 16 bytes implies AES-128. In the PHP code the AES variant must be explicitly specified, e.g. `aes-128-gcm`. A key that is too long is simply cut off, a key that is too short is padded with 0 values.
For example, if in the Java code a 16 bytes key is used for encryption (AES-128) and in the PHP code `aes-128-gcm` and the same key is applied for decryption, then the decryption is successful.

In case of further problems please post the used Java version, the error message and also complete sample data, i.e. key, plaintext and ciphertext.

---

Sample data:

```
Plaintext (UTF8):   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Key (UTF8):         0123456789012345
```

The Java code provides (under JDK 11) the following ciphertext (this is of course different for each encryption because of the randomly generated IV):

```
Ciphertext (Base64): 8DcD/QwKeFG1u2N1ve3mtsX1Lq7js33ESTigT2GH6Lrqrckh5I4qzkJMG3rnuJ9CSFZ1jai8LTChe3tuIJSMLmMTbUQ9mB0=
IV (hex):            f03703fd0c0a7851b5bb6375
```

This ciphertext can be decrypted by the PHP `decrypt` method using `aes-128-cbc` and the above key:

```
print(decrypt("8DcD/QwKeFG1u2N1ve3mtsX1Lq7js33ESTigT2GH6Lrqrckh5I4qzkJMG3rnuJ9CSFZ1jai8LTChe3tuIJSMLmMTbUQ9mB0=", "0123456789012345") . "\n");
```

Accordingly `aesGcmEncrypt` returns the same ciphertext if `aes-128-cbc`, the above key and the same IV are used (for the latter the randomly generated IV in the PHP code has to be replaced by the IV generated in the Java code, of course only for this test):

```
$iv = hex2bin('f03703fd0c0a7851b5bb6375'); // IV to use in aesGcmEncrypt
print(aesGcmEncrypt("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "0123456789012345") . "\n");
```